# foreach not updating element in array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to update a property in each element in my array to be a particular index. However when I try the following:

```
  static reindexComponentsOnMultiplePages(components) {
    return components.forEach((el, idx) => (el.componentIndex = idx));
  }
```

I get returned undefined.

My current array is as follows:

```
components = [ 
               [ {...}, {...}, {...} ], 
               [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] 
             ]
```

I was expecting each property in each element in my array to be updated. I call the method as follows:

```
pageComponents = MyService.reindexComponentsOnMultiplePages(pageComponents);
```

Comment: Yes, that's expected, the return value of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is `undefined`. What did you expect to get?

Comment: Do you mean to use `.map()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.forEach()` returns `undefined` as described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

There's no need to return the array, you are updating the items in your `forEach` loop.

```js
var arr = [{name: 'A', componentIndex: null}, {name: 'B', componentIndex: null}];
console.log(arr);

arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.componentIndex = index;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Just avoid returning anything, you don't need to.

Comment: Hi my array structure is as follows `components = [ [ {...}, {...}, {...} ], [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] ]` - basically an array of objects within an array of arrays.

Comment: And what is `componentIndex` to you? Imagine `[[A, B], [C, D]]` do you want you indices to be `[[0, 1], [0, 1]]` or `[[0, 1], [2, 3]]` ?